# can not send a post request using postman

Tags: http, post, httpclient, postman, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to sand post request using postman.
for some reason i am getting 400 Bad Request - Required request body is missing.
My controller is in spring boot environment.

My controller:

```
    @RestController
    public class HagarController {

      @PostMapping(value = "/hagar")
      @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
      public void hagar(@RequestBody String name, @RequestBody String id) 
      throws Exception{
          System.out.println("my name is: " + name +" id: " + id);
      }
    }
```

[The postman request img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPCH3.png)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, I hope it will help you:

```
@RestController
public class HagarController {

  @ResponseMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void hagar(@RequestBody String name, @RequestBody String id) 
      System.out.println("my name is: " + name +" id: " + id);
}
```

and in postman you probably added in Headers:
*see image*:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K7ez.png)

Comment: What about an explanation? It seems the only thing you added is `method = RequestMethod.POST`

Comment: I am not sure. I am new to postman also, but this method worked for me and I thought it will help Hagar as well.